# How to Convert date string with local time zone to universal time zone in c#, where string format is like yyyyMMddHHmmss TMZ?

Tags: c#, utc

I am receiving following date string from the XML sent to our service which is local US time.

20110928222614 CDT -> format is yyyyMMddHHmmss TMZ

I have to Convert this into Universal Time and store in our system, if anyone came across this problem, any solution to this will be great help ...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has a method [ToUniversalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx)

However, in order for this to be useful, your DateTimeKind on the DateTime must be in synch with your XML (e.g. if the XML uses xs:DateTime and you deserialize the date using WCF, then it will be set automagically).

Otherwise, you will need to create a new DateTime

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011, 09, 28, 22, 26, 14, DateTimeKind.Local);
```